# How to take direct print of crystal report using C# code

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to make a direct print of my report. I make a dialog box to set the printer settings, and I print using these settings, but an error like this occurs:

```
 at PrinttoPrinter line "missing parameter value "
```

This is my code:

```
ReportDocument rp = new ReportDocument();

rp.Load(@"my source");
PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();

PrintDialog pdialog = new PrintDialog();
if (pdialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    settings = pdialog.PrinterSettings;   
}

AttendenceR r = new AttendenceR();           
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();       
con.ConnectionString = "My connection string";      
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Here is my query");         
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                        
da.Fill(ds, "StudentDetails");                         

rp.SetDataSource(ds);                              
rp.PrintToPrinter(settings, new PageSettings() { }, false);
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: missing parameter values

Comment: i was trying to add printer settings in start and after this my query run and print the document

Comment: is anyone here who can answer my question

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running ExportToDisk in order to first ensure that you can generate a good PDF, then secondarily work on printing it. I suspect the PDF will not generate. You can add parameters using the SetParameterValue method. You can inspect the .rpt.cs codebehind file to see the indexes for each parameter.

```
rp.SetParameterValue(0, "Parameter Value");
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is still an issue for the OP **after almost 3 years**

Comment: I agree, but this could be useful for others who have similar problems. I've seen no shortage of posts about missing parameter values, and this will help others in the future.